# Inequality on the norm of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis

We define the operator $T$ from C[0,1] to the set of real numbers by $T(f) = \int_0^x f(x)dx$. I have to prove $||T^n||\leq 1/n!$. I can prove that norm of T is 1.

Comment: Induction seems appropriate

Comment: Welcome. You have to present your own working and thoughts as much as possible, so that the answerer doesn’t feel like they’re doing their homework for you, and so that they rather feel like they are helping you constructively.

Comment: @User2018 How do you define $T^n$ for maps $C([0,1])\to \mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Are you, by chance, looking at $T:C([0,1])\rightarrow T:C([0,1])$ defined through $$Tf(x):=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$$

Comment: @Thomas I am sorry for the mistake in the question

Comment: @Thomas - I've removed my question which seems to be the same as this question in order to avoid duplication. My apologies if this is a silly question, but how does one get the $n!$ in the denominator given in my deleted question, i.e. to show that $|T^nf(x)| \le \frac{x^n}{n!}$? As answer seems to show that $|T^nf(x)| \le \frac{x^n}{n}$ (without factorial)?

Comment: @user860374 thanks for pointing that out - it's a typo in my answer. The induction hypothesiy should already have a factor of $\frac{1}{n!}$, and, through the integration of $y^n$, another factor of $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is applied, resulting in the desired $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. For the start of the induction this is justified, as $2=2!$.

Comment: @Thomas, thank you very much for clarifying. :). I've upvoted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$|Tf(x)| =\left|\int_0^x f(t)\, dt \right|\le \int_0^x \left| f(t)\right|\, dt \le x ||f||_{C([0,1])}$$
So by monotonicity of the integral,
$$|T^2f(x) |\le \int_0^x y \, dy ||f||_{C([0,1])} = \frac{1}{2}x^2 ||f||_{C([0,1])}$$
If we assume, by induction,
$$|T^n f(x)| \le \frac{1}{n!}x^n ||f||_{C([0,1])}$$
we may conclude, by applying $T$,
$$|T^{n+1} f(x)| \le\int_0^x \frac{1}{n!}y^n\, dy\, ||f||_{C([0,1])}= \frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1} ||f||_{C([0,1])}$$
from which you can read off an upper bound for the norm of $T^{n+1}$.